# Site theme specific to sharepoint site collection?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

How can we restrict a site collection and its subsites to a particular site theme or set of themes?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Publishing enabled, you have a Master Page link in the Look and Feel section in Site Settings. You can force all subsites to inherit the masterpage from the top site, making the theme applied to that master page the one to show on all subsites, no matter what theme they have.

Also http://stsadm.blogspot.com/ has an extra option to stsadm that lets you apply a theme recursively.